# Can not test / deploy in an iPhone device? I get "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, audiotoolbox

Error:

> CodeSign /Users/edgarsifontes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BloggApp-fsjkfumdqbfxknenwfkgakigvosp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BloggApp.app/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework
>       cd /Users/edgarsifontes/Documents/BloggApp
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Edgar Sifontes (myIdisinHere)"
>
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign AD7CE038328B631655B9F6AA55CA8AE3DB6BDFDF --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --timestamp=none /Users/edgarsifontes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BloggApp-fsjkfumdqbfxknenwfkgakigvosp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BloggApp.app/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework
>
> /Users/edgarsifontes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BloggApp-fsjkfumdqbfxknenwfkgakigvosp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BloggApp.app/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please post more context/explanation than just the error... Try to explain the problem **in its simplest form**.

Comment: When I try to test the app in xcode it goes well for the mest but not when I try to deploy in a Iphone. I don´t know what more information you should need in other to understand my problem.

Comment: I would recommend editing the question, instead of adding the explanation as a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.